# Is there any JPAReader to read from database using spring batch?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

How to use JPA-Reader to read from database using spring batch with spring boot? Also need to insert records in bulk using JPA-Writer? How to do it using Spring batch? I am new to spring batch.

Comment: Where did you look and could not find answers to your questions?

Comment: Apologies my bad